# XBee cyclic sleep mode

Tags: xbee

I'm working on project for my "Smart house" and I'm trying to combine temperature sensors and others with motion detector. The idea is too sample temperature few times in a day (configurable variable), but also to start sampling immediately if motion sensor detector triggers.
I choosed to use Cyclic sleep with pin wake up, but for some reason it doesn't work as I expected. 
Here is example of how it works now:

1. Xbee in sleeping
2. I connecting Pin 9 to ground "-"
3. XBee wakes up sends few packets (configurable by sleep ST i guess) and goes to sleep. I did not disconnected pin 9 from ground!

I'm expecting that it will continue sending packets to me while it connected to ground (or in future motion sensors triggered)

Comment: Currently I've changed strategy and I will change Sleep mode when I receive triggered MotionDetector, but still the question is open, why it's not working like i've described.

Answer (score 0):

I received mail from DIGI support. Another thank you for them
e-Mail:

---

It’s an expected behaviour of module. In Sleep Mode 5 i.e. Cyclic Sleep with Pin Wake mode, module can be early wake by a high to low transition on pin 9 and not by continuously grounding pin 9.
If you wish module to wake and sleep solely based on pin 9 input, then you must enable Sleep Mode 1 i.e. “Pin Hibernate” mode.

Thanks
Ankur
Tech Support @ Digi

---